Feasibility and what tools should be put in place for this functionality?
Good morning,
I have been asked for a new feature but I am not sure of its feasibility
We have a call center that uses Aircall (In Lightning Experience)
I was asked that when a colleague picks up a call or calls a Contact, a popup is displayed on the Lightning Experience page they are on and which would display by default data relating to the Contact retrieved from various custom objects
The popup would :

Also, there would be menus in the popup, when clicking on a menu we would display information retrieved from other recordings
There should also be the possibility of saving information in the database about the Contact called or calling after filling in a text field in the popup.
It is mandatory to retrieve the id of the contact who calls the call center (or the id of the contact that the call center calls in order to display the correct information) in order to display their information in the popup or to save new information
I wonder if using Publish Event with cometd would be a solution
The better way to import cometD library into LWC, do you have any thoughts?
Also if using Publish event (with cometd?) answers the problem, do you agree that you should only use LWC (no Visualforce or Lightning Component Aura)
Or should I use a Trigger on the Activity object?
Thank you in advance for your help,

What about Option C - contact Aircall and ask them what's the recommended integration approach? They already have some of what you're asking about - https://aircall.io/en-gb/blog/customer-experience/salesforce-how-it-works-support-teams/
